# How to get the shortest simple path in a directed Graph with an additional constraint that it needs to use two arcs in the said path

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I have a directed graph that has positive weights (but there are reverse arcs) and I am trying to find the shortest path between a given source, `s` and a given sink, `t` but the path should also contain two given arcs in a sequence. Say we are given arcs `a1`, `a2`, we want to find a simple shortest path that goes from `s` to tail of `a1` and from head of `a1` to tail of `a2` and then from head of `a2` to the sink `t`. I was wondering if there is any elegant algorithm or even a mixed integer programming approach to solve this problem.

I am currently planning to modify Dijkstras algorithm to forbid certain nodes that have been previously added to the path.

Edit: I want the whole path from $s$ to $t$ to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Let arc $a1$ be $(u_1, v_1)$ and $a2$ be $(u_2, v_2)$. As you mentioned in your question, you want to find a simple shortest path that:

1. Goes from source $s$ to $u_1$
2. From $v_1$ to $u_2$
3. From $v_2$ to the sink $t$.

As you DAG has only positive weights, I think you should find the shortest paths for all three cases (using Dijkstra or any other algorithm) and join them together to get the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ satisfying the given constraints.

EDIT: As the question is for *Simple Path*, I will refer you to this: http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18438S12/lec22.pdf.

I am quoting a few important points here:

> 1. We first note that the arc-disjoint path problem, and the vertex-disjoint path problem in a directed graph are equivalent - i.e. we can give a polynomial-time reduction in either direction.
> 2. **Undirected Edge Disjoint Paths**. In the case of fixed k (i.e. there are k source-sink pairs), there is a polynomial-time algorithm to decide if there are edge-disjoint paths connecting each $s_i$,$t_i$ pair. This result follows from the Graph Minor Project of Robertson and Seymour (1995), and is very involved.
>      Yet for super-constant k, the undirected edge-disjoint paths problem is NP-complete. 22-1
> 3. **Directed Arc Disjoint Paths**. Even for $k = 2$ it is NP-complete to determine if there are arc-disjoint paths P1, P2 connecting s1, t1 and s2, t2. In fact, we can even choose s1 = t2 and s2 = t1 and this problem still remains NP-complete.

Comment: I tried this but there are reverse arcs and sometimes the path from $v_1$ to $u_2$ can visit the already visited vertex again.

Comment: Why do you think we shouldn't allow revisiting a vertex? You didn't mention that in your original question.
I know that in a shortest path a vertex is never repeated, but that is because we don't have the required condition of using a given arc.

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear. I wanted the whole path from $s$ to $t$ to be simple .

Comment: @prime_hit: Actually he did mention that in the question.  That's what a simple path is.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft True, my bad. I will update my answer.

Comment: w.r.t. the edit, what do edge-disjoint paths have to do with anything?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Read the reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you subdivide your two must-include edges creating a node right in the middle of the edge, you have an instance of requiring a simple path with two must-include nodes. The general problem (requiring $k$ must-include nodes) is studied here:

https://utd-ir.tdl.org/bitstream/handle/10735.1/2637/ECS-TR-EE-Vardhan-310316.85.pdf?sequence=7&isAllowed=y

(2009 paper, H. Vardhan et al, 9 authors in total)